# Updated Xcode isn't latest version

Tags: xcode, xcode7

I clearly updated Xcode in my Appstore to version 7.2, and it completed the update, but when I open the **`about Xcode`** window, it still shows version 7.1.1
Why hasn't it updated?[image]

[image]

Comment: What version is shown when you go to /Applications and click Get Info?

Comment: 7.1.1 It's very strange. The main problem is when I try to run a device, it shows the developer disk image error (because my device is iOS 9.2 and Xcode doesn't have that deployment target)

Comment: I have had this issue on another mac with the previous version. I'm assuming you've tried the regular troubleshooting step (restarting)?

Comment: Yes I have tried that

Comment: What about trashing the app and redownloading?

Comment: I haven't tried that. The app is quite large. But you think that will help?

Comment: I'm not sure about downloading from App Store, but you'd almost certainly get 7.2 if you downloaded the .dmg from the Apple Developer site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I too had similar problem.

Go to https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/

Click on additional tools and download the Xcode 7.2 dmg

Comment: Are you sure there is no other solution than to re-download it?

Comment: It worked for me. Its better than uninstalling and reinstalling from App store. At least you have older one around if installation from App store fails.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes if your OS has not had it's most recent update yet and you try to update XCode it can be buggy.

Could that be your problem?

Comment: No my OS and pretty much everything is latest version

Answer (score 0):

Hi only way is to uninstall the xcode and download the latest version from the apple developer website and install it